# How to display Parametric plots in different regions together?

Tags: plotting

I cannot find how  to plot the branches of a 'ParametricPlot' in different colors

```
x[a_] := 8*(6 + a)/(16 - a^2);
y[a_] := 2*(8 + 3 a)/(16 - a^2);
pl1 = ParametricPlot[{x[a], y[a]}, {a, -40, -4}, PlotStyle -> Red]
pl2 = ParametricPlot[{x[a], y[a]}, {a, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Green]
pl3 = ParametricPlot[{x[a], y[a]}, {a, 4, 12}, PlotStyle -> Black]
Show[pl1, pl2, pl3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Mesh->{{-4,4}}`.( The default `MeshFunctions->{#3&}`)

```
x[a_] = 8*(6 + a)/(16 - a^2);
y[a_] = 2*(8 + 3 a)/(16 - a^2);
ParametricPlot[{x[a], y[a]}, {a, -40, 12}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Green, Black}, 
 Mesh -> {{-4, 4}},PlotRange -> 10,(* MeshFunctions->{#3&}*)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add the `PlotRange` option to your `Show` statement, like this:

```
Show[{pl1, pl2, pl3}, PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-5, 5}}]
```

We might ask what happens at $a=-4$?  Why don't the three lines intersect at this point?  Use `Manipulate` to see why:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{pl1, pl2 , pl3,
   Graphics[{PointSize[.02], Cyan, Point[{x[a], y[a]}]}]},
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-5, 5}}],
 {a, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: Indeed the manipulate helps understand parametric curves with several branches, Thanks!